# South: How to rename a model with a name containing uppercase letters?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

Thanks to the nice docs provided by the amazing app South, I managed to successfully rename a model using the code below:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    db.rename_table('myapp_a_model', 'myapp_another_model')

def backwards(self, orm):
    db.rename_table('myapp_another_model','myapp_a_model')
```

However, the real name of the model contains upper-case letters, i.e. myapp_A_Model, and I want to rename myapp_A_Model to myapp_Another_Model. The uppercase letters matter to me. The challenge is that the code below:

```
db.rename_table('myapp_A_Model', 'myapp_Another_Model')
```

doesn't work. How do you rename a model into one with uppercase letters?

Comment: I think it may be a database issue. Which database are you using? PostgreSQL? MySQL? Anyway, it would be great if you say why do you need to have a case-sensitive database table name because if not, it seems to be just a whim...

Comment: I figured cap words was part of a naming convention in Django? http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names -- I am using PostGres

Comment: CapWords are used for class names. But you are dealing with table names, right? And the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#table-names) say: "It is recommended that you use lowercase table names, if possible [...]. Django uses lowercase table names when it auto-generates table names from models"

Comment: That's good to know! Sigh, I should have read these docs earlier. Cheers! But I take it then that there is no way of accomplishing the above?

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, there was a bit of confusion on my end.

Django model names can be uppercase while PostGres tables names can all be lowercase.